# How do I scroll to a certain widget in a QScrollArea

Tags: python, qt, pyqt, pyqt5

For example: 
In PyQt5, if I have several `QGraphicsView` inside a `QScrollArea`, how do I set the QScrollBar to let certain one of the `QGraphicsView` to be at the top of `QScrollArea`?

[image]

`QScrollArea` doesn't have a function like `scrollToItem` of `QTableWidget`.
I can `setValue` of `QScrollBar`, but I can't get the position of a certain Widget inside the `QScrollArea`.

```
print(self.graphicsView.pos().y()) # gets 0
```

Comment: I don't seem to understand your question but i can only draw 2 meanings. 1. Do you want only one `QGraphicsView` to show by each scroll?           2. Or you want each `QGraphicsView` to have a scroll area in their parent scroll area?

Comment: I suspect they may want it to work like html anchors work. So the ability to scroll to a widget so that the top of the widget is at the top of the scroll area (or as close as possible)? That was my interpretation, but I might be wrong.

Comment: @three_pineapples Yes, just like that.

Comment: @NanaOsaberima. Just like three_pineapples said. I have edited the question.

Comment: QScrollArea has ensureWidgetVisible() which is like scrollToItem().